# How to make it as a string

Tags: regex

Input : `<div5 id="abc" style="....">xyz</div5>`
I want to assign this to a string variable but because of quote ,this cannot be directly assigned to a string variable .
How can I take this input .
So that I can assign to a string variable

Comment: In java or c++?

Using stdin?

Comment: As your wish choose any language

Comment: @zac input like this : <asabas id="abc">sjsjsjsjjjdsj<absbdb>

Comment: Description is not clear. Please add some details.

Comment: Not sure what you mean you can't assign that to a string because of the quote... what language are you using to assign this? normally with anything that needs to contain a quote in the string the the way you would do it is `myStringValue = "<div5 id=\"abc\" style=\"....\">xyz</div5>" `

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to escape the quotes:

```
#include <iostream>

std::string x = "<div5 id=\"abc\" style=\"....\">xyz</div5>";
```

The same goes for Java:

```
String x = "<div5 id=\"abc\" style=\"....\">xyz</div5>;
```

To get it from the user in C++:

```
#include <iostream>

std::string x;
std::getline(std::cin, x);
```

And in Java:

```
String x = new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<strirng>
using namespace std;
int main() 
 { string a,b;
 getline(cin,a,'\"');//input end when there is a  "
 getline(cin,b,'\"');//because " is a wide space character,need to put\ 
                      before it
 cout<<a<<"  "<<b<<endl;
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: `\"` doesn't need to be escaped because it is a wide-character it needs to be escaped because it is a reserved character.  The sequence for storing a wide-character is `L'a'`